# how can i execute this code faster?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb, ado

in my Billing form, i have a button to insert the datagridview data into two access databases.
i used this code to insert to first database:

```
    Private Sub inserttotblbill()
    Dim billcon As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constr)
    Dim billcmd As New OleDbCommand

    For i = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        billcon.Open()
        billcmd.Connection = billcon
        billcmd.CommandText = ("insert into tblbill(inum,snum,idate,cname,iname,iprc,iqnt,ipaid,itotal,iuser,itype) " _
                & " values('" _
                & TextBox1.Text _
                & "','" _
                & TextBox6.Text _
                & "','" _
                & TextBox2.Text _
                & "','" _
                & TextBox3.Text _
                & "','" _
                & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value _
                & "','" _
                & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value _
                & "','" _
                & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value _
                & "','" _
                & TextBox4.Text _
                & "','" _
                & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value _
                & "','" _
                & username _
                & "','" _
                & Label2.Text _
                & "')")
        If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(dgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dgv.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
        End If
        billcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        billcon.Close()
    Next i
  end sub
```

i used this code to insert to second database:

```
    Private Sub inserttoreport()
    Dim rptcon As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\report.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=KNOZ1003")
    Dim rptcmd As New OleDbCommand

    For k = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        rptcon.Open()
        rptcmd.Connection = rptcon
        If dgv.Rows(k).Cells(4).Value = "101" Then
            rptcmd.CommandText = ("insert into tab1(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13) " _
            & " values('" _
            & TextBox1.Text _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox6.Text _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox2.Text _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox3.Text _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(0).Value _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(1).Value _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(2).Value _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox4.Text _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox5.Text _
            & "','" _
            & Label2.Text _
            & "','" _
            & username _
            & "','" _
            & xxxx _
            & "')")

        ElseIf dgv.Rows(k).Cells(4).Value = "102" Then
            rptcmd.CommandText = ("insert into tab2(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13) " _
            & " values('" _
            & TextBox1.Text _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox6.Text _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox2.Text _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox3.Text _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(0).Value _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(1).Value _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(2).Value _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox4.Text _
            & "','" _
            & dgv.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value _
            & "','" _
            & TextBox5.Text _
            & "','" _
            & Label2.Text _
            & "','" _
            & username _
            & "','" _
            & xxxx _
            & "')")
        End If
        rptcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        rptcon.Close()
    Next k
  End Sub
```

But when i press the button to perform the above code, it takes a while
how can i make it faster?

Comment: This question looks like belonging to CodeReview SE.

Comment: first: Change your Code to use sqlParameters. Then you will have no Problems with string containing ' and/or ,     (and avoid SQL injection). Second: Please define "it takes a while". How Long for how many records? And, dont open the Connection for each record. This costs a lot of time.

Comment: This may be on-topic for Code Review, if **A** the code works, **and B** it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way. If you do decide to post, please read the help center before posting.

Comment: Use a bound datagridview - update the datatable instead of using SQL to do the updates/inserts.

Answer (score 5):

As the very first thing, do move the connection out of the loop:

```
billcon.Open()
billcmd.Connection = billcon
For i = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
    ' ...
Next
billcon.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multi Thread to speed up the code.
[Task Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

This also version for vb. Try to use background thread for height weight handle.